# Receiving 1971021 error when I try to finalize any install

Tags: oculus-rift

So Windows was giving me some troubles this weekend, and suffice it to say that I had to reinstall my OS.  Instead of wiping my drive, I just installed over the previous installation, preserving all my files so that they wouldn't need downloading again.

I've run the Oculus installer twice since reinstalling Windows, but when I try to install any game that requires additional actions after downloading (games and apps that require the "Finish Install" action), I get a 1971021 error.  This happens for both fresh installs (I uninstalled one of the apps and then tried to reinstall it, as well as installing an app I never downloaded prior to reinstalling Windows) as well as for the games that I had backed up.  The exact error text is:

> Redistributable info missing. Internal error when we're missing info for a required redistributable package.

Presumably this means the Visual C++ redistributable packages, which I've run for the 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, and 2015 versions (both x86 and x86_64).  I've also tried setting the owner of the folder to "Administrators" (as that is what most folders in Program Files are set to) without any luck.

Searching for this error code through Google and the Oculus site doesn't return anything useful.

What is causing this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I'm thinking there may be some file ownership problems, which is something I may try to fix when I get home from work.

Comment: Setting the ownership didn't work.  I've submitted a ticket to Oculus, and will update here if they provide a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* you still have a copy of your old <kbd>Redistributables</kbd> folder, you might be fine.  Copy that, plus the <kbd>Software</kbd> folder into the Oculus installation folder, and restart Oculus Home.  The full instructions can be found [here](https://support.oculus.com/1715420212071737/).

If you didn't back up that folder (or have since deleted it), you might be SOL, and will have to download those games again.

Comment: I guess I should mention that I had to redownload all my games, since I had deleted the backup of my redistributables folder.  Luckily my internet is pretty fast, so it didn't take too long.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new user with admin rights, then try again and it will work. This is  profile issue, while under new account go into old profile under Apps go into each folder and delete any folder titles oulus. Then sign into old profile, oculus setup will run again, but quickly, now open game.