# What do I need to backup when reinstalling the Oculus software?

Tags: oculus-rift

Let's say I need to reinstall the Oculus software.  Either it's been misbehaving, or I had to [reinstall Windows](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/271577/1351), or I've built a new computer.  I really don't want to have to download everything again.  What do I need to save in order to spend the least amount of time downloading stuff later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this support article](https://support.oculus.com/1715420212071737/), you need to save the <kbd>Software</kbd> and <kbd>Redistributables</kbd> folders.  From the link, the full instructions are as follows:

> To backup app data:
>
> - Close the Oculus App.
> - Open the Oculus folder (located in the drive that Oculus is installed to).
> - Locate the Software folder and copy this directory (C:\Program Files\Oculus\Software or X:\Oculus\Software) to a backup location on your computer.
> - Locate the Redistributables folder and copy this directory (C:\Program Files\Oculus\Redistributables or X:\Oculus\Redistributables) to a backup location on your computer.
>
> To restore from backup:
>
> - Close the Oculus App.
> - Open the Oculus folder (located in the drive that Oculus is installed to).
> - Copy the saved Software directory back into C:\Program Files\Oculus or X:\Oculus.
> - Copy the saved Redistributables directory back into C:\Program Files\Oculus or X:\Oculus.
> - Restart the Oculus App through the settings:
>
>   - Open the Oculus App, select the gear icon on the upper right.
>   - Select Settings.
>   - Select Beta from the menu on the left.
>   - Click Restart Oculus.
>
> Your apps should now be available under "Installed" in your Library.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy and then paste, you'll lose your saved games. To backup entire Oculus installation or only games, you can try a freeware called [Oculus Backuppe](http://www.aomeitech.com/oculus-backup.html)r.

Comment: I have used a method similar to the post above. As for the comment about losing your saves, I never lost my saves and its been reported on oculus reddit that the "oculus backupper" is malware. Youre better off moving things around yourself following a guide.